# How to add symbol inside mapbox flutter

Tags: flutter, mapbox, mapbox-gl, mapbox-marker

so far I have used mapbox_gl package of flutter and after trying the example, I would like to add marker in mapbox using SymbolOptions, the examples show how to add marker by clicking the button, so is there a way to add symbol directly when I load the page?
here is part of the example code

```
void onMapCreated(MapboxMapController controller) {
    mapController = controller;
    print(mapController);
    mapController.addListener(_onMapChanged);
    _extractMapInfo();

    mapController.getTelemetryEnabled().then((isEnabled) {
      setState(() {
        _telemetryEnabled = isEnabled;
      });
      
    });

    // mapController.addCircle(
    //   CircleOptions(
    //       geometry: LatLng(-6.198122, 106.845861), circleColor: "#FF0000", circleRadius: 200),
    // );
  }
```

Comment: I found this link helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61403824/flutter-mapbox-symbol-on-click-open-google-maps

Comment: @Kamlesh Hi.. thank you very much for your information

Answer (score 0):

You can add the symbol by simple using the controller.

```
controller.addSymbol(SymbolOptions(
  geometry: LatLng(17.361431, 78.474533),
  iconSize: 2.0,
  iconImage: 'assets/icons/bitmap_truck_.png',
));
```

You can call this code in your MapBoxMap Widget like this:

```
MapboxMap(
        initialCameraPosition: _initialCameraPosition,
        accessToken: kMapboxAccessToken,
        styleString: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v12',
        onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
        onStyleLoadedCallback: (){
         controller.addSymbol(SymbolOptions(
         geometry: LatLng(17.361431, 78.474533),
         iconSize: 2.0,
         iconImage: 'assets/icons/bitmap_truck_.png',
         ));
        },
      ),
```

Let me know if this helped.